# How to animate and rotate my car on map like uber in Android?

Tags: android, navigation, android-animation, google-maps-markers

I want to animate and rotate my car on Map like uber in android. and i am saving location on Firebase realtime database. and also getting location from firebase realtime.

my code is below-------->

```
private void subscribeToUpdates(final String driver_id) {
     ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getString(R.string.firebase_path));


   childListener= ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarker(dataSnapshot, driver_id);
            Log.v("datanap", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarker(dataSnapshot, driver_id);
            Log.v("datanap", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

and i am creating my map marker and updating in this code here. And i have tried some animation and rotation method but it did not work properly.

```
private void setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String driver_id) {

    // When a location update is received, put or update
    // its value in mMarkers, which contains all the markers
    // for locations received, so that we can build the
    // boundaries required to show them all on the map at once
    String key = dataSnapshot.child(driver_id).getKey();
    Log.v("datasnap", key);

    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        startPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        Log.v("startPos", String.valueOf(startPosition));

   //     marker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.truck_top)).flat(true));
        mMarkers.put(key,mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.truck_top)).flat(true)));
        Log.v("trackLog", "Marker created");
    } else {

        endPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        Log.v("endPos", String.valueOf(endPosition));

        mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
      //  startBikeAnimation(startPosition,endPosition,key);

        Log.v("trackLog", "Marker updated");
        //    animatedMarker(startPosition, endPosition, mMarkers.get(key));

    }

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();


    for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    if (!isAnimated) {
        isAnimated = true;
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 300));
    }

}
```

I have tried this code..

```
private void startBikeAnimation(final LatLng start, final LatLng end, final String key) {

    Log.i(TAG, "startBikeAnimation called...");

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME_PER_ROUTE);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            //LogMe.i(TAG, "Car Animation Started...");
            v = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
            lngg = v * end.longitude + (1 - v)
                    * start.longitude;
            latt = v * end.latitude + (1 - v)
                    * start.latitude;

            LatLng newPos = new LatLng(latt, lngg);

            mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(newPos);
            mMarkers.get(key).setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
            mMarkers.get(key).setRotation(getBearing(start, end));

            // todo : Shihab > i can delay here
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition
                            (new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(newPos)
                                    .zoom(15.5f)
                                    .build()));

            startPosition = mMarkers.get(key).getPosition();

        }

    });
    valueAnimator.start();


}


public static float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

    if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
    else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: _"And i have tried some animation and rotation method but it did not work properly."_ What did you try and how it did not work?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen i have update what i have tried. please have a look.